# How to offer a specific group of people the full app for free

Tags: ios, testing, app-store-connect, testflight

I just uploaded my app to iTunes. Theres is a free and full version(coasts money) of the app, but I would like to offer a group of people (10 - 30 individuals) the full app for free permanently. Whats the best way to do so?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about distribution rather than programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called **Promo Code**.

> Promo codes can be redeemed through any store territory where your app
>   is available and are good for four weeks from the day they’re
>   generated. They become invalid if a new version of the app becomes
>   available or if your contract with Apple expires. Each promo code
>   generated for an app can be used one time to download the app.

Read [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ProvidingPromoCodes.html) how to generate and use these codes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, we managed to send a beta version to a few friends! And sorry for the late reply